# Switching from one even listener function to another

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having trouble accessing my second event listener function after the first one is called. I am relatively new to javascript so it might just be the structure of how I'm calling my functions.

Here is my code for my 'fire' method that is referenced in the event listener calls:

```js
//Make sure you are not clicking on the row/col labels
    if (row > 0 && col > 0) {
        if (gameBoard[row][col] == 0) { //Check for a miss
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            //Set the value in the matrix to a 3 to indicate a miss
            console.log(e.target.id);
            gameBoard[row][col] = 3;
            turnCt++;
            return;
        }else if{
        //More conditionals for my other cases
        }
    }
```

Here is what it looks like when I'm calling my functions:

```js
if (turnCt % 2 == 1) {
    drawTopGameboard("Two");
    drawBottomGameboard("One", gameBoardOne);

    topContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        fire(e, gameBoardTwo, "Two")
    }, false);
    console.log("First conditional");
} else {
    drawTopGameboard("One");
    drawBottomGameboard("Two", gameBoardTwo);

    topContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        fire(e, gameBoardOne, "One")
    }, false);
    console.log("Second conditional");
}
```

I am ultimately trying to switch the boards that are getting clicked on after one square is clicked (just like the the typical battleship game). My issue lies in the second code snippet because no matter how many turns are taken, I never print "Second Conditional" to the console. That leads me to believe that I'm never leaving the first event listener function.

Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the order. You are assigning either one or the other event listener on page load because of the if else. Instead, assign the event listener once and check for the condition in the handler.

```
topContainer.addEventListener('click' function(e) {
    if (turnCt % 2 === 1) {
        fire(e, gameBoardTwo, "Two");
    } else {
        fire(e, gameBoardOne, "One");
    }
}, false);
```

Now `turnCt` will be evaluated always after the click occurred.